# MySQL behaviour when statement has conflicting where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I was looking through some code today and I found an interesting MySQL statement, and wondered how MySQL deals with statements that have conflicts in their logic.

Here is a very basic example of what I am talking about:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1 AND id != 1;
```

I ran this on one of my databases and it returned 0 rows, but my question is, will this always return 0 results? Also how does MySQL decide whether a row should be returned when there is a conflict like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *conflict*. MySQL evaluates the `conditions one by one, and and it turns out that you just have two conditions that cannot be true at the same time.

This:

```
WHERE id = 1 AND id != 1;
```

Actually means:

```
WHERE 1 != 1
```

> will this always return 0 results?

So the answer is yes, this query will never return a record.

Comment: I just woke up and realised that I had had basically just asked how conditional logic worked... “Why does true && false = false?”. This is why you should never post questions after a long day. Thanks for taking your time to answer it GMB